# Deviant Art API or SDK for iPhone?

Tags: ios, deviantart-api

Do you have any idea if there is available an official DeviantArt API or SDK for iPhone?

I am building an application and I would like to integrate a search through Deviant Art public feed. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official API or SDK for the iPhone. From reviewing their forums, it has been suggested many times, but so far has not been provided.

There's something called DiFi: http://www.botdom.com/documentation/DiFi that may be worth a try.

If that doesn't work, you could try interacting with the web site using a hidden UIWebView by using the `– stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method. I've used this in the past to interact with web sites that do not provide an API.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't find what I need here. Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @Andrei, I added another paragraph to my answer - I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It seams that this is the only way. I have sent an E-Mail to deviantART support and if I will get another answer from them, I will post it here.

Answer (score 2):

That's a wonderful idea, Andrei, but I don't think deviantart has any APIs available. However, what you want to do might not be impossible, you would just need to build your app to work with deviantart's website.

Comment: …which, of course, means that the app would break if they changed their site in any number of ways.

Comment: @Jeff Kelley, Yep. That's certainly correct. I guess that's one of the risks of doing it that way, and it's up to you to determine if it's a risk worth taking.

I've done things like this before, where i've manually made an app to work with some website. The way I do it is that I have the app query a file I have on my server. In that file, I do all the heavy lifting in terms of integrating with the website. This way, if they change their site in any way, I don't have to re submit the app, I just need to change my server side file and it's back in no time :)